# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "kapieren", "verstehen", "nachvollziehen" und wie sollte ich sie am besten benutzen?

Tags: verb-usage

Man kann die Verben "kapieren", "verstehen" & "nachvollziehen" ins Englische als "understand" übersetzen. Allerdings habe ich fast immer nur "verstehen" gehört/gelesen. Das Verb "kapieren" ist besonders interessant, weil es ähnlich dem entsprechenden Italienischen Wort "capire" ist.

Nun, wie sollte ich diese Verben am besten verwenden? Gibt es Situationen, wo ein bestimmtes Verb besser als das andere ist?

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Gibt es denn eigene Beispiele, die die eigene Unsicherheit für das eine oder andere hervorheben? Oder anders gefragt: gibt es Beispiele, die Anlass für diese Frage waren? Daran lässt sich manchmal leichter erklären, weil deutlich wird, wo das Verständnis noch fehlt.

Comment: Nein, ich war einfach nur neugierig...

Comment: Natürlich entspricht "kapieren" dem italienischen "capire" - beide haben dieselbe lateinsche Wurzel (vgl. die Antworten). Im Deutschen wird übrigens gelegentlich auch "capito?" verwendet (vgl. https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/capito_). Würde ich aber nicht empfehlen  ...

Answer (score 1):

Sie sagen alle dasselbe, aber es sind verschiedene Sprachebenen.

"Kapieren" ist sehr umgangssprachlich und liegt im Bereich zwischen lässig und rotzig, d.h., wenn du das einem höheren Chef sagst, kommt das ziemlich aufsässig herüber.

"Verstehen" ist absolut neutral und passt immer.

"Nachvollziehen" ist schon leicht höheres Sprachniveau und liegt leicht über "verstehen", d.h. es klingt recht gebildet, aber trotzdem ist es immer auch noch normal akzeptabel unter wenig Gebildeten oder wenn du es zu einem Punk auf der Straße sagst.

Answer (score 0):

Du hast Recht, alle diese Verben sind eng miteinander verwandt und können alle als "to understand" ins Englische übersetzt werden.

- *kapieren* stammt vom Lateinischen *capere* ("fangen", "fassen") ab, welches auch die Wurzel von Italienisch *capire* ist. Es ist etwas weniger förmlich als *verstehen*. Grob gesagt, würde man *kapieren* dann verwenden, wenn man im Englischen *to get* verwenden würde.
- *nachvollziehen* ist etwas förmlicher bzw. gehobener als *verstehen*. Man kann es in etwa als "to comprehend" ins Englische übersetzen. Wenn man ausdrücken möchte, dass man das Verhalten einer Person intellektuell verstehen kann, dabei aber offenlassen will, ob man dieses Verhalten auch gutheißt, dann würde man eher zu *nachvollziehen* greifen. Auch wenn auch *nachvollziehen* diese Konntation hat, so ist die Konnotation "billigen", "gutheißen" bei *verstehen* stärker als bei *nachvollziehen*.

---

You are right, these verbs are closely related in meaning and they all can mean "to understand"

- *kapieren* actually stems from Latin *capere* ("to grasp", "to get"), which is also the root to Italian *capire*. It is slightly more informal than *verstehen*. Roughly, you would use *kapieren* when you would use *to get* in English.
- *nachvollziehen* is more formal, and translates better to "to comprehend". In case you want to express that you can (intellectually) understand what someone did, but want to leave open, whether you endorse the behavior, you would rather use *nachvollziehen* instead of *verstehen*, because *verstehen* has a scent of "accepting", "approving". *nachvollziehen* has a bit of this scent as well, but it is less strong there, I'd say.

Comment: Tut mir leid, aber diese Antwort ist in meinen Augen absolut nicht hilfreich. Die Unterschiede zwischen *kapieren*, *verstehen* und *nachvollziehen* sind so viel größer als du es hier simplifizierst, dass ich dieser Antwort ein -1 geben muss, auch wenn ich selbst ( - oder vielleicht gerade weil mir das klar ist? - ) gerade zu wenig Zeit habe, um auf all die Dinge einzugehen, die hier eine Rolle spielen.

Comment: @Olafant OK :) Dann ist meine Antwort wohl einfach falsch und ich weiß es wirklich nicht besser. Genau dafür ist das Downvoten ja erfunden worden :) Wenn du Zeit hast, schreib doch mal noch eine bessere Antwort. Dann wäre allen geholfen, auch mir :)